# MySQL: Merging two tables together

Tags: mysql, merge

Just wondering, if I have two tables that have some common columns (might be in different order though) and some different columns, is there an easy way to merge the two structures together so that both of them would have the same columns?

I tried exporting the structure of both and merging the files together aiming to have a create query that creates a merged table but because the common columns are not in the same order I end up trying to add the same column twice.

Or maybe if there's a query like:

```
ALTER TABLE `example` ADD IGNORE...
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the fields that are not in common?

Comment: are you trying to permanently join them into 1 table, or join them for queries?  (so each table remains distinct when you are done)

Comment: @pala_ add them, alter the structure of the result table to have all the columns of the two tables.

Comment: @Doon permanently join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what worked for me was exporting both tables' structures and taking their add column queries in an excel column and removing the duplicates and just creating a new query with the unique queries that were left which are the unique columns in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `union all` query:

```
select col1, col2, col3, NULL as col4, col5
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4, NULL as col5
form table2;
```

Comment: Can't use that, the tables have different number of columns

Comment: @NaguibIhab . . . Of course you can use `union all`.  You simply include the columns that are common between the tables.

Comment: I understand the concept, but it's not working with me i'm still trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. However (in the next comment) is this a correct query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM proj_sjcs.cms_clients
UNION ALL
SELECT *,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM proj_sjcs_orig.cms_clients

Comment: what error do you get when it's not working? you have to make sure the columns from both tables line up, and are in the same order. insert `null` for a field that doesn't match

Comment: @NaguibIhab . . . Don't use `*`.  List the columns out explicitly.

Comment: It's not coming up with an error, but the result is not what I expected. table proj_sjcs_orig.cms_clients has 57 fields, table proj_sjcs.cms_clients has 62 fields, the result of the query gave me a table with 57 fields while I expected that it should be atleast 62 fields or more given the different fields that table 1 has and table 2 doesnt. Does that make sense?

Comment: select the second table first and you will get 62 fields. Your column line up is not complete. try post your columns of both tables and let Gordon help you line them up.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at 'JOIN' so if `your_table` has more records and you need some additional columns from `your_second_table` and tables are connected by some `common_field` column in both you can:

```
SELECT t.*, t2.*
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN your_second_table t2
ON t.common_field = t2.common_field
  AND t.another_common_field = t2.another_common_field
```